# ArrayAdapter in Android Project

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adapter for a custom layout of listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878548/adapter-for-a-custom-layout-of-listview)

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
JSONArray productsList = null;
try {
    productsList = obj5.getJSONArray("Content");
} catch (JSONException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}

if(productsList != null){
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    for (int i=0; i<productsList.length(); i++) {

    final String[] items = new String[productsList.length()]; 

    String product = null;

    try {       
        product = productsList.getJSONObject(i).getString("Quantity")+" X "+
            productsList.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name") +"         "+
            Currency.britishPound+productsList.getJSONObject(i).getString("MinCost");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(product!=null){                  
        items[i]=product;                       
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(APIQuickCheckout.this, R.layout.product_item, R.id.label, items);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Here is my list view:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="30">
</ListView>
```

And here is how I pass each product seperately.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
 </TextView>
```

Now and according to the the aforementioned code I'm passing to each line just a simple string. However, I was wondering how could I pass three different Strings. The reason that I want to pass three different Strings is that I want them to be in the following format:

```
Quantity X 
Number                          Price(this should be at the end of the line)
```

Comment: No, it is NOT a duplicate of the QA mentioned. The question there is how to work without cursor, the question here - how to place string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to derive from adapter, and provide properly filled views.  Like here:

https://github.com/ko5tik/camerawatch/blob/master/src/de/pribluda/android/camerawatch/CameraAdapter.java

For better performance  consider:

- reusing views supplied to getView() method#
- utilise viewHolder patern to save getViewById() resolution